# Entity Framework error about member no supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want get all the records between two times:

```
var Check1 = db.WorkingTs
               .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.WorkingTime).Value.TimeOfDay >= FTime.TimeOfDay 
                        || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.WorkingTime).Value.TimeOfDay <= FBtime.TimeOfDay 
                        && x.FlightsCid == Crewstuff.id)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

but I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'Time Of Day' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

I also tried `DbFunctions.CreateTime()`, but the same error still appears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new DateTime variable first. And then use it in youre query.

```
var fTime = FTime.TimeOfDay;
var bTime = FBtime.TimeOfDay;

var Check1 = db.WorkingTs.Where(x => 
DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.WorkingTime.Hour, x.WorkingTime.Minute, x.WorkingTime.Second) >= fTime  
|| DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.WorkingTime.Hour, x.WorkingTime.Minute, x.WorkingTime.Second) <= bTime 
&& x.FlightsCid == Crewstuff.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Btw you can use FirstOrDefault() instead of Where()

```
var fTime = FTime.TimeOfDay;
var bTime = FBtime.TimeOfDay;

var Check1 = db.WorkingTs.FirstOrDefault(x => 
DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.WorkingTime.Hour, x.WorkingTime.Minute, x.WorkingTime.Second) >= fTime  
|| DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.WorkingTime.Hour, x.WorkingTime.Minute, x.WorkingTime.Second) <= bTime 
&& x.FlightsCid == Crewstuff.id);
```

Comment: You still can't do `.Value.TimeOfDay`.

Comment: Just edited the answer. This should work

Comment: thanks alot @IlyaCosmosTaraskin worked !!